# rustc "cannot return value referencing temporary value" with recursive data type

Tags: rust

In a beginners project I want to develop end-game data tables (EGTB) for a chess program. Given a position on the board, one should be able to look up the position in the database and eventually get a move to play. Sounds easy?

However, because EGTBs tend to become very large, symmetries are employed to reduce the data size. For example, in a game without pawns, it is enough to have only the positions with the white king in the lower left quarter in the EGTBs, since all other positions can be obtained by mirroring horizontally or vertically or both.

Example: In the EGTB, there is the position with white king on c2, black king on a2 and white rook on c4. If it is white's turn, the move Ra4 (c4a4) will be recommended as this is mate for black. However, the symmetrical position with white king on f2, black king on h2 and white rook on f4 is **not** in the EGTB.

Turns out that it may be necessary to perform a series of transformations on a given position to find an equivalent symmetrical position in the EGTB. And of course, the recommended move from the EGTB position must undergo the same transformations in reverse order to make sense in the original position. In the example, we need to return f4h4 as recommended move in the position where the white king is on f2.

And because said transformations may apply to different object types (moves, positions, etc.) i came up with the following generic type:

```
pub enum Mirrored<'a, T> where T: Copy+Sized+Mirrorable<'a> {
    Identity(T),   // T value not transformed
    Horizontal(&'a Mirrored<'a, T>), // T value mirrored horizontally
    Vertical(&'a Mirrored<'a, T>),   // T value mirrored vertically
}
```

Note: we need the ugly reference things because otherwise rustc complains the type would be infinite. Once we use references, it complains about value of type T might not live long enough and we would need lifetimes. (Not sure there is an easier way? This is just the result of attempts to make rustc happy. And it's not nice, is it?)

And then I thought it would be nice to have a trait Mirrorable with two functions mirrorH and mirrorV thus:

```
pub trait Mirrorable<'a> where Self: Sized+Copy {
    fn mirrorH(self) -> Mirrored<'a, Self>;
    fn mirrorV(self) -> Mirrored<'a, Self>;
}
```

So far so good, until I tried to implement `Mirrorable` to `Field`. `Field` is basically  an enum A1, A2, ..., H7, H8 and the operations on it are manipulations on u8 values.

```
impl<'a> Mirrorable<'a> for Field {
    /// Mirror the field on horizontal middle axis.
    /// Changes to corresponding rank on other side, e.g. c6 <-> c3
    fn mirrorH(self) -> Mirrored<'a, Field> { Horizontal(&Identity(Field::fromFR(self.file(), 9 - self.rank()))) }
...
```

rustc now complains because it "cannot return value referencing temporary value".
I understand that `Identity(...)` is such a temporary value and `&Identity(...)` is the reference to it. But **how can I** say: please, put this somewhere on the heap if you must or wherever, I don't care.

In C/C++, I'd malloc() some space and then I'd have a permanent reference to a `Mirrored` value. But how am I supposed to do this in Rust?

Also, do I expect too much from rustc? It could see that it can copy the basic mirrorable value into the `Identity(..)` structure and that this data must be on the heap. So, where's the problem anyway?

Comment: Use a [`Box`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/boxed/index.html).

Comment: @Jmb Ahh!. I see. So `Box` is the way to tell rust we want to use the heap (which we don't really want, but must due to the forced boxing in the recursive type).

Comment: well, if you really want to going crazy https://crates.io/crates/ouroboros, the name is a warning. and some understanding of why it's a bad idea https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/.

Comment: cool, thank you @Stargateur this looks like exactly the thing I need to read.